# MacOS GameKit leaderboards fail to load with App "does not support leaderboards" error

Tags: macos, cocoa, game-center, gamekit, game-center-leaderboard

I'm attempting to integrate a macOS game with Apple's GameKit SDK using Objective-C. So far I have been able to authenticate the user and load/update achievements, but I have had no success with leaderboards.

When attempting a `loadLeaderboardsWithCompletionHandler` request, I get this error:

> Error Domain=GKErrorDomain Code=3 "The requested operation could not
>   be completed due to an error communicating with the server."
>   UserInfo={GKServerStatusCode=5043, NSLocalizedDescription=The
>   requested operation could not be completed due to an error
>   communicating with the server., NSUnderlyingError=0x600000158960
>   {Error Domain=GKServerErrorDomain Code=5043 "status = 5043, MyGame
>   does not support leaderboards" UserInfo={GKServerStatusCode=5043,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=status = 5043, MyGame does not support
>   leaderboards}}}

When trying

```
  GKLeaderboard * leaderLoader = [[GKLeaderboard alloc] init];
  leaderLoader.identifier = @"grp.lvl1";
  [leaderLoader loadScoresWithCompletionHandler` ...
```

The completion handler is never called.

I'm having trouble understanding why Apple's endpoint says my game does not support leaderboards. So far I have:

1. Enabled GameCenter for our app identifier
2. Enabled GameCenter on our app's App Store Connect page (currently in "prepare for submission" state)
3. I've added a leaderboard to our app group via the Features menu in App Store Connect and imported it onto the macOS App Store page

But still nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: might be worth re-highlighting that this is the macOS version of an app that is also being built for iOS. Both app identifiers are in the same app group so they can share game center data.

Answer (score 0):

If your leaderboard is in a group, it seems to break. Mine was working fine until I added it to a group, then it just broke. Removing it started it working again. Be interested to hear if it fixes it for you, could be worth filing a radar.